# Function which() in R

Tags: r, for-loop, syntax-error

I am writing a for loop for this

```
n<-nrow(Example) #Example has two only variables but the for loop attempts to expand and work also for approx 500.
Newdata<-matrix()
loops<-ncol(Example)-1 #number of loops
for(i in 1:loops){
  #Example[,1] is the the guide column and thus this doesn't change in the loop
  nhat<-which(Example[1,i+1]==Example[,1]) #finds the position of the first date in column 2 according to the first column
  nend<-which(Example[n,1]==Example[,2]) #finds the position of last date in col 2 according to the first column
Newdata[,i]<-c(rep(NA,nhat-1),Example[1:nend,i+1],NA) #creates the new data
}
```

However when I run it i get this error:

`Error in Ops.data.frame(Example[1, 2], Example[, 1]) : 
  ‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames`

If I use this:
`which(Example$V2[1]==Example$V1)`
the program runs smoothly, except I can't iterate it for every column if I use the `$`. Any suggestions on how to tackle the issue?

[Example Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ikody7jglj8rxpg/Example.xlsx?dl=0) or

The `dput` output (mini version because the full version does not fit in here):

```
dput(Example[1:100,c(1:3)])
structure(list(`1` = structure(c(820540800, 820627200, 820713600, 
820800000, 821059200, 821145600, 821232000, 821318400, 821404800, 
821664000, 821750400, 821836800, 821923200, 822009600, 822268800, 
822355200, 822441600, 822528000, 822614400, 822873600, 822960000, 
823046400, 823132800, 823219200, 823478400, 823564800, 823651200, 
823737600, 823824000, 824083200, 824169600, 824256000, 824342400, 
824428800, 824774400, 824860800, 824947200, 825033600, 825292800, 
825379200, 825465600, 825552000, 825638400, 825897600, 825984000, 
826070400, 826156800, 826243200, 826502400, 826588800, 826675200, 
826761600, 826848000, 827107200, 827193600, 827280000, 827366400, 
827452800, 827712000, 827798400, 827884800, 827971200, 828057600, 
828316800, 828403200, 828489600, 828576000, 828921600, 829008000, 
829094400, 829180800, 829267200, 829526400, 829612800, 829699200, 
829785600, 829872000, 830131200, 830217600, 830304000, 830390400, 
830476800, 830736000, 830822400, 830908800, 830995200, 831081600, 
831340800, 831427200, 831513600, 831600000, 831686400, 831945600, 
832032000, 832118400, 832204800, 832291200, 832550400, 832636800, 
832723200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), `2` = structure(c(995587200, 
995846400, 995932800, 996019200, 996105600, 996192000, 996451200, 
996537600, 996624000, 996710400, 996796800, 997056000, 997142400, 
997228800, 997315200, 997401600, 997660800, 997747200, 997833600, 
997920000, 998006400, 998265600, 998352000, 998438400, 998524800, 
998611200, 998870400, 998956800, 999043200, 999129600, 999216000, 
999561600, 999648000, 999734400, 999820800, 1000080000, 1000684800, 
1000771200, 1000857600, 1000944000, 1001030400, 1001289600, 1001376000, 
1001462400, 1001548800, 1001635200, 1001894400, 1001980800, 1002067200, 
1002153600, 1002240000, 1002499200, 1002585600, 1002672000, 1002758400, 
1002844800, 1003104000, 1003190400, 1003276800, 1003363200, 1003449600, 
1003708800, 1003795200, 1003881600, 1003968000, 1004054400, 1004313600, 
1004400000, 1004486400, 1004572800, 1004659200, 1004918400, 1005004800, 
1005091200, 1005177600, 1005264000, 1005523200, 1005609600, 1005696000, 
1005782400, 1005868800, 1006128000, 1006214400, 1006300800, 1006473600, 
1006732800, 1006819200, 1006905600, 1006992000, 1007078400, 1007337600, 
1007424000, 1007510400, 1007596800, 1007683200, 1007942400, 1008028800, 
1008115200, 1008201600, 1008288000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), `3` = structure(c(820540800, 820627200, 820713600, 
820800000, 821059200, 821145600, 821232000, 821318400, 821404800, 
821664000, 821750400, 821836800, 821923200, 822009600, 822268800, 
822355200, 822441600, 822528000, 822614400, 822873600, 822960000, 
823046400, 823132800, 823219200, 823478400, 823564800, 823651200, 
823737600, 823824000, 824083200, 824169600, 824256000, 824342400, 
824428800, 824774400, 824860800, 824947200, 825033600, 825292800, 
825379200, 825465600, 825552000, 825638400, 825897600, 825984000, 
826070400, 826156800, 826243200, 826502400, 826588800, 826675200, 
826761600, 826848000, 827107200, 827193600, 827280000, 827366400, 
827452800, 827712000, 827798400, 827884800, 827971200, 828057600, 
828316800, 828403200, 828489600, 828576000, 828921600, 829008000, 
829094400, 829180800, 829267200, 829526400, 829612800, 829699200, 
829785600, 829872000, 830131200, 830217600, 830304000, 830390400, 
830476800, 830736000, 830822400, 830908800, 830995200, 831081600, 
831340800, 831427200, 831513600, 831600000, 831686400, 831945600, 
832032000, 832118400, 832204800, 832291200, 832550400, 832636800, 
832723200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), .Names = c("1", 
"2", "3"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Thus the output if the code works looks like this:

```
DatesV1     DatesV2
 ...         ...
17/07/2001  NA
18/07/2001  NA
19/07/2001  19/07/2001
20/07/2001  20/07/2001
21/07/2001  NA
...         ...
```

Comment: Hello. I have uploaded the data for the reproducible example. This will show everything that generates the error. The second worksheet in the data uploaded shows the expected output if the code works.

Comment: Please don't provide data through file hosters. Most SO members are loath to download random files from third-party website. Instead include minimal & representative sample data using e.g. `dput` to make your post plus code self-contained.

Comment: Hmm i understand and see your point. Will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data are stored as a tibble, rather than as a base dataframe.  Base dataframes have `drop=TRUE` as their default, so that `df[,1]` returns a vector (not a dataframe).  Tibbles have `drop=FALSE` as their default, so `df[,1]` is still a tibble/dataframe.  When this is the case, it doesn't make sense to test two dataframes of different dimension for equality using `==`, because dataframes are not recycled like vectors.  You have two options,

Option 1: clear out the tibble-ness by resetting the class of your dataframe

```
class(Example) <- "data.frame"
```

Option 2: add `drop=TRUE` every time you subset with square brackets, as in:

```
Example[n,1,drop=TRUE]
```